# Different Result from MinMaxScaler() with Manual Calculations

Tags: python, math, scikit-learn, scaling

So i was tinkering with MinMaxScaler and want to see how it works with manual calculations
here's the array i'm trying to scale

```
array = [[0, -1.73, -1.73, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.73], 
        [-1.73, 0, -1.41, -1.73, -1.73, -1.73, -1.41], 
        [-1.73, -1.41, 0, -1.73, -1.73, -1.73, -0.0], 
        [-2.0, -1.73, -1.73, 0, -1.41, -1.41, -1.73], 
        [-2.0, -1.73, -1.73, -1.41, 0, -0.0, -1.73], 
        [-2.0, -1.73, -1.73, -1.41, -0.0, 0, -1.73], 
        [-1.73, -1.41, -0.0, -1.73, -1.73, -1.73, 0]]
```

the lowest value is `-2.0` and highest value is `0`. When i do my manual calculations it is based on `MinMaxScaler()` formula stated in [sklearn minmax](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) but when i program it, it shows different result as in this code

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np

X = np.array([
[0, -1.73, -1.73, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.73], 
[-1.73, 0, -1.41, -1.73, -1.73, -1.73, -1.41], 
[-1.73, -1.41, 0, -1.73, -1.73, -1.73, -0.0], 
[-2.0, -1.73, -1.73, 0, -1.41, -1.41, -1.73], 
[-2.0, -1.73, -1.73, -1.41, 0, -0.0, -1.73], 
[-2.0, -1.73, -1.73, -1.41, -0.0, 0, -1.73], 
[-1.73, -1.41, -0.0, -1.73, -1.73, -1.73, 0]
])

# create an instance of MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

# fit the scaler to the data and transform the data
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X)

# print the scaled data
print(X_scaled)
```

The Result Array is

```
[[1.        0.        0.        0.        0.        
0.        0.       ]
 [0.135     1.        0.1849711 0.135     0.135     
0.135     0.1849711]
 [0.135     0.1849711 1.        0.135     0.135     
0.135     1.       ]
 [0.        0.        0.        1.        0.295     
0.295     0.       ]
 [0.        0.        0.        0.295     1.        
1.        0.       ]
 [0.        0.        0.        0.295     1.        
1.        0.       ]
 [0.135     0.1849711 1.        0.135     0.135     
0.135     1.       ]]
```

My Calculations

```
x' = (x-min)/ (max⁡ - min)
x' = (-1.73-(-2)) / (0⁡ -(-2)) 
x' = 0.135
```

My question is where did i do my calculations differently than sklearn ? why is -1.73 becomes 0 ?

Comment: Did you actually use this code `(-1.73-(-2))/0⁡ -(-2) `? There's a division by zero in the formula. Try calculating it separately (-1.73-(-2) = 0.27; 0-(-2)=2; 0.27/2=0.135)

Comment: sorry, i'll edit it

Comment: `X.min(axis=0)` is not just `-2`, it's actually `array([-2.  , -1.73, -1.73, -2.  , -2.  , -2.  , -1.73])`. This is because of the `axis=0` parameter.

Comment: but still it gives me `0.135` but sklearn result is `0`

Comment: But it's not. That is -1.73 becomes either 0 or 0.135 (see last sub-array). @Stef looks to be right on the money on why you see it turn to 0 in some cases.

Comment: Compare `X.min(axis=0)`, `X.min(axis=1)` and `X.min()`. `X.min()` is the global minimum; `X.min(axis=0)` is the minimum for each column, and `X.min(axis=1)` is the minimum for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is scaling each *column* of the array. -1.73 becomes 0 only if it is the smallest value in that column. Notice how -1.73 does not become 0 in the first column.

This is intentional and it is due to the `axis=0` argument.

If you want to scale each element of the array according to the min and max of the entire array you could do something like this:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np

X = np.array(
    [
        [0, -1.73, -1.73, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.73],
        [-1.73, 0, -1.41, -1.73, -1.73, -1.73, -1.41],
        [-1.73, -1.41, 0, -1.73, -1.73, -1.73, -0.0],
        [-2.0, -1.73, -1.73, 0, -1.41, -1.41, -1.73],
        [-2.0, -1.73, -1.73, -1.41, 0, -0.0, -1.73],
        [-2.0, -1.73, -1.73, -1.41, -0.0, 0, -1.73],
        [-1.73, -1.41, -0.0, -1.73, -1.73, -1.73, 0],
    ]
)

# create an instance of MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

# fit the scaler to the data and transform the data
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X.reshape(-1, 1)).reshape(*X.shape)

# print the scaled data
print(X_scaled)
```

Comment: why it's only finding `max` and `min` in the column and not the whole array ?
isn't better to know `-1.73` is to equivalent of `0.135` to entire array ?

Comment: It is due to the `axis=0` argument in `X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))`. The docs say that this estimator scales and translates each feature individually such that it is in the given range on the training set, e.g. between zero and one. sklearn expects that each column of the array represents a different feature.